# Powershell Copy-To - If Destination Directory exists, copies into Existing Directory

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Right I have a simple `Copy-Item` script to copy files from one destination folder to another.

#### releasecode.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$source, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$destination
) 
Process {
    Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Recurse -Force
```

I'm running `releasecode.ps1` using the following command line:

> .\releasecode.ps1 -source "C:\test\from" -destination "C:\test\to"

The `from` folder has the following structure:

```
.
├── from
├── stain.txt
├── test1.txt
├── folder
|   ├── test2.bmp
```

This correctly copies to (On the *first copy*):

```
.
├── to
├── stain.txt
├── test1.txt
├── folder
|   ├── test2.bmpthe
```

If I re-ran it straight afterwards, the `from` folder is created as a directory within `to' instead of just overwriting the existing structure:

```
.
├── to
├── stain.txt
├── test1.txt
├── folder
|   ├── test2.bmp
├── from
|   ├── stain.txt
|   ├── test1.txt
|   └── folder
|       ├── test2.bmp
```

How do I just overwrite the existing `to` directory structure if the files and folders exist currently.

#### More Information

- Running this on a Windows Box
- `$PSVersionTable`:

[image]

Comment: That is a `Copy-Item` gotcha. To avoid it create a missing destination folder first, then copy into that folder. Otherwise use `robocopy`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Thank you very much, that comment pointed me in the right direction (I check to see if the folder exists, if it does I rename it first). Feel free to add an answer and I shall expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into a `Copy-Item` gotcha related to copying source directories.

If the destination exists and is a folder the cmdlet copies the source *to* the destination.

```
Copy-Item C:\src\a C:\dst\b -Recurse

C:\                 C:\
├─dst               ├─dst
| └─b               | └─b
└─src               |   └─a
  └─a           ⇒   |     ├─bar.txt
    ├─bar.txt       |     └─baz.txt
    └─baz.txt       └─src
                      └─a
                        ├─bar.txt
                        └─baz.txt
```

If the destination does not exist the cmdlet copies the source *as* the destination.

```
Copy-Item C:\src\a C:\dst\b -Recurse

C:\                 C:\
├─dst               ├─dst
└─src               | └─b
  └─a               |   ├─bar.txt
    ├─bar.txt   ⇒   |   └─baz.txt
    └─baz.txt       └─src
                      └─a
                        ├─bar.txt
                        └─baz.txt
```

The customary way of handling this in PowerShell is to ensure that the destination folder exists first, *then* copy the *content* of the source folder:

```
if (-not (Test-Path $destination)) {
    New-Item -Type Directory -Path $destination | Out-Null
}
Copy-Item -Path $source\* -Destination $destination -Recurse -Force
```

Alternatively you can use [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy), which does not have this issue:

```
robocopy C:\src\a C:\dst\b /s
```